# Problem running actix-web as Windows service

Tags: rust, windows-services, actix-web

I'm trying to use [windows-service](https://github.com/mullvad/windows-service-rs) to run an actix web app. It provides a nice API and mostly works. I can start my service just fine. However, when I try to stop my service, I get the following error: `Error 109: The pipe has been ended` (it does stop the service however).

I'm mostly just using the example provided for `windows-service`, but here is the relevant code (for context and all the wrapper functions, check out https://github.com/mullvad/windows-service-rs/blob/master/examples/ping_service.rs):

```rust
pub fn run_service() -> Result<()> {

    fn hi() -> impl actix_web::Responder {
        "Hello!\r\n"
    }

    let sys = actix_rt::System::new("test");

    actix_web::HttpServer::new(move || {
        actix_web::App::new()
            .route("/", actix_web::web::get().to(hi))
    })
    .bind("0.0.0.0:3000").unwrap()
    .start();

    let event_handler = move |control_event| -> ServiceControlHandlerResult {
        match control_event {
            ServiceControl::Interrogate => ServiceControlHandlerResult::NoError,
            ServiceControl::Stop => {
                actix_rt::System::with_current(|s| s.stop());
                ServiceControlHandlerResult::NoError
            }
            _ => ServiceControlHandlerResult::NotImplemented,
        }
    };

    let status_handle = service_control_handler::register(SERVICE_NAME, event_handler)?;

    status_handle.set_service_status(ServiceStatus {
        service_type: SERVICE_TYPE,
        current_state: ServiceState::Running,
        controls_accepted: ServiceControlAccept::STOP,
        exit_code: ServiceExitCode::Win32(0),
        checkpoint: 0,
        wait_hint: Duration::default(),
    })?;

    sys.run().unwrap();

    status_handle.set_service_status(ServiceStatus {
        service_type: SERVICE_TYPE,
        current_state: ServiceState::Stopped,
        controls_accepted: ServiceControlAccept::empty(),
        exit_code: ServiceExitCode::Win32(0),
        checkpoint: 0,
        wait_hint: Duration::default(),
    })?;

    Ok(())
}
```

If I put the `System::stop` in a `thread::spawn`, I get a different error: `The service did not return an error. This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error`. In this case it does not stop the service.

I've put in some logging, and it doesn't look like the code ever gets past the `sys.run().unwrap()`, which is strange.

Any thoughts? I've never used the Windows Service API before so I don't really know what I'm doing.

**EDIT**

I figured out what the main issue is: I have to notify Windows the service has stopped before stopping the service. I put together a clunky way to make it work:

```rust
std::thread::spawn(move || {
    loop {
        if shutdown_signal.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {

            status_handle.set_service_status(ServiceStatus {
                service_type: SERVICE_TYPE,
                current_state: ServiceState::Stopped,
                controls_accepted: ServiceControlAccept::empty(),
                exit_code: ServiceExitCode::Win32(0),
                checkpoint: 0,
                wait_hint: Duration::default(),
            }).unwrap();

            actix_rt::System::current().stop();
            break;
        }
    }
});
sys.run().unwrap();
// ...
```

where `shutdown_signal` is an `AtomicBool` I set to true in the event handler. I'm going to see if I can do this instead somehow through `actix_rt`.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. I think this is the best way to handle it, though I would be happy to see other solutions!

```rust
pub fn run_service() -> Result<()> {

    use futures::Future;

    fn hi() -> impl actix_web::Responder {
        "Hello!\r\n"
    }

    let sys = actix_rt::System::new("test");

    actix_web::HttpServer::new(move || {
        actix_web::App::new()
            .route("/", actix_web::web::get().to(hi))
    })
    .bind("0.0.0.0:3000").unwrap()
    .start();

    let (mut send_stop, recv_stop) = {
        let (p, c) = futures::sync::oneshot::channel::<()>();
        (Some(p), c)
    };

    let event_handler = move |control_event| -> ServiceControlHandlerResult {
        match control_event {
            ServiceControl::Interrogate => ServiceControlHandlerResult::NoError,
            ServiceControl::Stop => {
                send_stop.take().unwrap().send(()).unwrap();
                ServiceControlHandlerResult::NoError
            }
            _ => ServiceControlHandlerResult::NotImplemented,
        }
    };

    let status_handle = service_control_handler::register(SERVICE_NAME, event_handler)?;

    status_handle.set_service_status(ServiceStatus {
        service_type: SERVICE_TYPE,
        current_state: ServiceState::Running,
        controls_accepted: ServiceControlAccept::STOP,
        exit_code: ServiceExitCode::Win32(0),
        checkpoint: 0,
        wait_hint: Duration::default(),
    })?;

    actix_rt::spawn(recv_stop.map(move |_| {
        status_handle.set_service_status(ServiceStatus {
            service_type: SERVICE_TYPE,
            current_state: ServiceState::Stopped,
            controls_accepted: ServiceControlAccept::empty(),
            exit_code: ServiceExitCode::Win32(0),
            checkpoint: 0,
            wait_hint: Duration::default(),
        }).unwrap();

        actix_rt::System::current().stop()
    }).map_err(|_| ()));

    sys.run().unwrap();

    Ok(())
}
```